# How to access JSON from an iframe originating from same domain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my webpage a hidden iframe is loaded with some JSON in it. This JSON is refreshed by some actions on the page. How do I access this JSON in iframe from my web page?  for some unknown arcane unexplainable reason I am forced to use jQuery 1.3.2. so no `$.parseJSON()`

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as your outer page?

Comment: Yes, the title of the question says this, "originating from same domain?"

Comment: ah, sorry I missed that :) Does your frame have an id attribute? If not can you add one to it (That will make it easier to select and faster)

Comment: well iframe has an ID `hiddeniframe`, creativity at its best, I can do `$('#hiddeniframe')` but what next?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
var json = $.parseJSON($("#hiddeniframe").contents().text());
```

Something along those lines will work at least.

Comment: I sadly inform you that I am forced to live in stone age and use jQuery 1.3.2

Comment: @kumar, are you able to use a different library like https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js to parse it? You always have the option of using `eval()` but that should be a last resort.

Comment: @kumar, or would you be able to use jQuery's getJSON(), loading the contents of the iframe through ajax instead of in a frame?

Comment: no worries, you have pointed me in right direction, I have text now, how do I parse it is a different question altogether, thanks :)

Comment: @Kumar, glad I could help a bit haha :)

Comment: Why not use jQuery no conflist mode and use a newer version of query aliased to $jqXXXX (XXXX being the version number)?

Answer (score 8):

All modern browsers include a JSON parsing library:

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#hiddeniframe").contents().text());
```

If you need to support older browsers there are several libraries to choose from that will provide the same interface. The better ones will check to see if the browser is providing a native implementation and not override it, since it's bound to be faster.

See also `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 1):

The code @Paulpro posted:

```
var json = $.parseJSON($("#hiddeniframe").contents().text());
```

doesn't work for me.

I changed the code to:

```
var json = $.parseJSON($("#hiddeniframe").contents().find("*").first().text());
```

And now it works.